# Laravel Background Image just on Login Page

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

I work on an Laravel 5.4 Project and i want an Background Image just for the `login.blade.php` not for `home.blade.php` or other sites.

If i change the `Body` Background its on all Pages of course, whats the best why to do it on just the login page?

Thanks

Comment: Add css class on body tag if its login route and in css do the background styling stuff

Comment: Can you explain it more please? On Html its easy but laravel..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class to your body if your are in your login page like

```
<body class="{{ Request::path() == 'login' ? 'background-image' : '' }}"></body>
```

and than add css for class

```
.background-image{
    //your code for background image set
}
```

Comment: Thanks i try it out:)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options:

1. Create a `<script type="text/javascript"> document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')"; </script>` and place it in login.blade.php. That is a fast, but a bad plan.
2. Use blade sections (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade)! Make your body tag in layouts/app.blade.php look like:

   `<body @section('body-changes', '')>`

   And in your login.blade.php:

   `@section('body-changes') style='background-color: red;' @endsection`
3. Best way: create a section having all additional styles, like `@section('styles', '')` and put it before your `</body>` in layouts/app.blade.html, and then whenever you want to create additional style for your page just

   `@section('styles') <style type='text/css'> your-css-here </style> @endsection`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the requested route

```
<body class="{{ Request::is('/login') ? 'image' : '' }}">
```

and then the following css

```
body.image {

}
```

A much easier and cleaner way is to use the [Ekko](https://github.com/laravelista/Ekko) package by laravelista. It provides support for active route and active url.